# Multiple AutoFilter Criteria?

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I have a table in my spreadsheet that I use with AutoFilters. The columns in the table are:

Date
Name
Company
Type
Premium
Agent

I need to be able to filter by the date and also the company. So far, this is the code I'm working with for applying the auto filters:

```
With ActiveSheet
    .AutoFilterMode = False
        With .Range("A1:F1")
             .AutoFilter
             .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=">=" & Me.boxDateBegin.Value, _
             Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & Me.boxDateEnd.Value
             .AutoFilter field:=3, Criteria1:="Bear River Mutual"
        End With
End With
```

The only problem is that this doesn't seem to be applying the second filter (field:=3). Did I do something wrong?

*Edit not by OP but from OP's Comment*

**Turns out the filter works good**

Comment: Use the macro recorder.

Comment: I thought the same thing but it is in ColumnC, spelled exactly the same, and matches up to the dates in ColumnA.

Comment: You don't have a blank row in row 2 do you? This filter would fail if there was.

Comment: Turns out the filter works good, but showing the data in my listbox is still giving me some trouble...

Comment: No mention of a listbox here. What are we missing?

Answer (score 0):

Below code might help you..

`With ActiveSheet
    .AutoFilterMode = False
        With .Range("A1:F1")
             .AutoFilter
             .AutoFilter field:=1, Operator:=xlFilterValues, Criteria1:=">=" & Me.boxDateBegin.Value, _
             Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & Me.boxDateEnd.Value
             .AutoFilter field:=3, Criteria1:="Bear River Mutual"
        End With
End With`